# htaccess clean url for Joomla component

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, clean-urls

I give up. I have read through dozens of questions on here, even asked my own, I have tried numerous things, I just don't know what to do anymore.

I need to create url's out of the following formats: (NSFW links, be warned)

```
http://jbthehot.com/#page=1

http://jbthehot.com/home?func=viewphoto&id=2969

http://jbthehot.com/home?page=4

http://jbthehot.com/home?func=viewalbum&aid=75
```

I must be retarded because I simply do NOT understand htaccess. I try not to ask for all-done answers, but in this case, an actual clear, copy/paste answer for at least one of the above formats would really be helpful. 
I repeat, I have tried a lot of things, so I'm obviously doing something wrong, or I'm not understanding the rules and conditions right, so a copy/paste answer that is SURE to work would really help me understand what I'm doing wrong here.

If it helps, the component used here is SIM Gallery, on Joomla and there are a couple of other rewrite rules in effect in the .htaccess , here they are:

```
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L] 
#
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want htaccess to do for you here? How do you want your "clean" urls formatted?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/viewphoto/([0-9]+)$ home?func=viewphoto&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^home/viewalbum/([0-9]+)$ home?func=viewalbum&aid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^home/page/([0-9]+)$ home?page=$1 [L]
```

So `http://jbthehot.com/home/viewphoto/2969` would show you `http://jbthehot.com/home?func=viewphoto&id=2969`, etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear example, but it didn't work. That's what I don't get, no matter what I try, every example and combination, it's as if nothing happens..I removed the 2 first lines since they were already in the Joomla native htaccess, tried with the 2 lines, no change..I'm at loss.

Comment: Have you tried removing everything else? You might have conflicting conditions.  There could also be server settings preventing this.